# How do I write a JQuery function to populate a div from an html select?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Below is my simple Javascript function.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('getImage.php', function(data) {
          $('#imageSelector').html("<select>" + data + "</select>");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="imageSelector">
    </div>

    <div id="imageArea">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP script used to get the data.

```
<?php
  include 'connect.php';

  $sql = "SELECT products_id, products_image FROM products";
  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
  while ($Array = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $imageEcho .= '<option value=' . $Array['products_id'] . '>' . $Array['products_image'] . '</option>';
  }
  echo $imageEcho;
?>
```

Below is the function used to complete the URL path to the image.

```
 function getImage(image) {
    document.getElementById("imageArea").innerHTML="<img    src=../eoas/images/"+image+" alt='' />";
}
```

Maybe I can't do it this way but I thought I would check to see if anyone knows.

Comment: is `$Array['products_image']` a public url to the image?

Comment: Hello, Thanks for asking this question. Below is another function I use to complete a URL to the location of the image. function getImage(image) {
  document.getElementById("imageArea").innerHTML="<img src=../eoas/images/"+image+" alt='' />";
 }

Answer (score 1):

You need smth like this :

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
       $.get("getImage.php", 
            function(data){ 
                  $( '#imageSelector' ).attr('src', data); 
       }); 
 });
```

Use Chrome developer tools to understand what data is in ajax answer

Here is [article](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-loading/) about it

And it would be much better to use JSON answers

Comment: live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xzirrow/LPcYh/) jsFiddle -but it's impossible to use **img** inside **option**

Comment: Hi I am new on this forum. Are we allowed to paste code into these Add Comment form fields?

Answer (score 1):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PsuH4/) using the jsFiddle API.

```
$.get('getImage.php',function(data){
    // data = '<option value=...>...</option><option ...>...</option>...';
    $('<select>').html(data).appendTo('#imageSelector');
});
```

Comment: Thanks I will try using jsFiddle.

Comment: Hello, I posted this question a while back and since have tried some different methods of producing a drop down menu and found a technique that works. Now I need to pass a selected value from the drop down menu I created with the following code.

Comment: @user3512348: You're better off creating a new question with what you have. Show the code, what you've tried, the current result and the desired result and I'm sure you'll get an answer. But don't do it in this question as it would most likely be too confusing.